# Will iPhone change its timezone automatically if I fly on an airplane?

Tags: time

Let's say, I have time settings set to automatic update.

With airplane mode on and off (both cases), would my phone update timezone automatically?

Answer (score 2):

If your iPhone finds your location and you're in a new time zone, it'll change the time.

With Airplane Mode off:
Your iPhone will be silently using location services and will update the time based on your location change.

With Airplane Mode on:
GPS and Cellular (two of the three methods an iPhone uses to determine your location) are disabled, but you can enable wifi still. Even without connecting to in-flight wifi, but as long as there is in-flight wifi, your iPhone can determine a time zone change based on location info provided by that wifi network (which Gogo inflight does but I'm not sure about ViaSat).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will get the time from the cell towers, check this [topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39649/how-did-iphone-4-know-to-switch-timezone-in-airplane-mode) for details.

Comment: The question asked for airplane mode on and airplane mode off cases. Are you suggesting it will get the time from cell towers when in airplane mode?